# Is it possible to make an application private in windows store?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

I have created an Windows 8 store application for a small business using visual studios 2012, C# and xaml. The problem I am having is when I side load the application it requires a developer license every 30 days which the company is not happy with. The company do not want the application made available to the public hence my hesitation to put the application on windows store. So as side loading does not seem acceptable are there any suggestions on how to make an application private (only downloadable by people I choose) in windows store?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micham/archive/2014/05/30/sideloading-store-apps-to-windows-8-1-devices.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. You can perform sideloading without developer licence, but Enterprise or Professional version of Windows is required.
2. System Center allows you to deploy private app to the company managed devices. Windows Intune allows you to create private Company App Hub
3. There is promise to create Windows Store for businesses, where apps will be available only for company employess, or contractors. Azure Active Directory accounts will be required. http://www.techradar.com/news/software/business-software/microsoft-will-launch-windows-store-for-business-with-windows-10-1292471

Answer (score 0):

Go for Windows store. On the process of creating your app in the store you can select several availability of your app. 
1. Make app available publicly
2. Restrict to certain countries
3. Only the people you allow can download the app (people you chose must have a live account)
4. Make the app visible via a URL. (People who had the URL can access the app)
5. Use promotional code. (People who have the code can access the app)

Only drawback is some of these options will only work if the end users are using Windows 10. 
Let me know if you require more info. I've done this before.